# How to include Azure Function secrets when deploying to Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-aks

I have built a .NET Core Azure Function using a ServiceBusTrigger.  The function works fine when deployed in a regular App Service plan once the appropriate Application settings, such as the Service Bus connection string.

However, I would prefer to host the function as a Docker container on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).  I have AKS setup and have a number of .NET Core Docker containers running fine there, including some Azure Functions on TimerTriggers.

When I deploy the function using the ServiceBusTrigger, it fails to properly tun and I get "Function host is not running." when I visit the functions IP address.  I believe this is because the app settings are not being found.

The problem is I do not know how to include them when hosting in the Docker/Kubernetes environment.  I've tried including the appropriate ENV entries in the Docker file, but then I cannot find the corresponding values in the deployment YAML viewed via the Kubernetes dashboard after I've successfully run `func deploy` from PowerShell.

Most of the Microsoft documentation addresses the TimerTrigger and HttpTrigger cases, but I can find little on the ServiceBusTrigger when using Docker/Kubernetes.

So, how do I include with the appropriate app settings with my deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this Blog ：[Playing with Azure Functions kubernetes integration](https://medium.com/@tsuyoshiushio/playing-with-azure-functions-kubernetes-integration-9048908bfc2a), you could find a description about add environment variables.

In the deployment.yml, add the env(like `AzureWebJobsStorage` as an environment variable).

```
containers:
    - image: tsuyoshiushio/queuefunction-azurefunc
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: queuefunction-deployment
      env:
        - name: AzureWebJobsStorage
          value: YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING_HERE
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
```

Then apply it, it will works.